# how to install imagemagick for php7 on ubuntu?

Tags: php7, imagemagick

well, just after upgrading my Ubuntu and therefore moving to php7, I seem not to be able to install imagick extension for php using the same old command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

I get this error (tried php7-imagick too)

```
 Package php5-imagick is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-imagick' has no installation candidate
```

what should I do?

Comment: I think it is just `sudo apt install php-imagick`.

Comment: Can confirm, `apt-cache search` shows that `php-imagick` is the package for php7.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Just do:

```
sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```

This should install `imagick` for PHP 7.0.

Comment: On my system this tries to install php 5.5 along with it.

Comment: I got: WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  php-imagick
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-7.0/ubuntu/ trusty/main php-imagick amd64 3.4.0~rc6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-7.0/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php-imagick/php-imagick_3.4.0~rc6-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Worked, but I had to follow @alexg advice to restart service php7.0-fpm

Comment: You may need to run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` (or `apt-get dist-upgrade` prior to running `apt-get install php-imagick`

Comment: Don't forget to restart apache if PHP7 is running as an apache module.

Comment: Cover your bases better: `sudo apt install php-imagick && sudo systemctl restart nginx.service apache2.service php7*` -> That should cover/restart most popular webservers and fpm. (If you aren't using it, it's ignored)

Comment: So much thanks. I stay trying fix for 4h! For complete you aswers, just add: "sudo service apache2 restart"

Answer (score 40):

Turns out I had to restart the fpm:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm reload
```

Things I tried:

`apt install php-imagick` didn't work for me. The module was getting loaded for the PHP CLI (I checked with `php -m | grep -i imagick` but through my nginx webserver it didn't show up in the list of modules reported by `phpinfo()` at all.

I even inserted `extension=imagick.so` to `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` manually, just to make sure.

I then tried purging the `php-imagick` package and installing from cpan:

```
sudo apt install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick php-dev
sudo pecl install imagick
```

And still, no cigar. It would work through the cli but not via nginx.

Comment: Necromancer here, sorry, but gush after 30 minutes your line mentioning the restart of php service made me really feel like I should bang my head into the brick wall... :) Yes you guessed it, I forgot that bit and I was going mental why it's not working :D

Comment: @alexg since we aren't compiling imagemagick is there any reason using `-dev` package of `libmagickwand`?

Comment: @inckka no, you should be OK with the binary package. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

For php 5.6: `sudo apt-get install php5.6-imagick`

For php 7.0:`sudo apt-get install php7.0-imagick`

For php 7.1: `sudo apt-get install php7.1-imagick`

For php 7.2: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-imagick`

For php 7.3: `sudo apt-get install php7.3-imagick`

For php 7.4: `sudo apt-get install  php7.4-imagick`

For php 8.0: `sudo apt-get install php8.0-imagick`

For php 8.1: `sudo apt-get install php8.1-imagick`

After restart apache:`sudo service apache2 reload`

Comment: Can't believe this was so far down a rabbit hole, this is perfect - thanks.

Comment: Only thing that worked!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Works great! This must be the answer on top!

Comment: That is the only code that works!. thanks man.

Answer (score 10):

Installed these packages:

```
sudo apt install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick php-dev
sudo pecl install imagick
```

Now replace:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm reload
```

With:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Works Great

Comment: its worked for me

Comment: What are "libmagickwand-dev imagemagick php-dev" used for? I see those libraries have a hard size

Answer (score 3):

Now it is 2018, just wanted to highlight, in many cases, you would also want to install php-gd along with php-imagick (if you are installing this for wordpress for example).

```
sudo apt install php-imagick php-gd 
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

The use of php-imagick implies php7.2-imagick if 7.2 is what your php version is.

Comment: php-gd is [optional](https://make.wordpress.org/hosting/handbook/handbook/server-environment/#php-extensions) if you have imagick installed

Comment: Seems this works for many people but for me, running ***sudo apt install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick php-dev*** says *imagemagick is already the newest version* but that there are unmet dependencies. When I try to install the dependency, it says there is another and so forth for about a half-dozen different ones, none of which will install. The last one is for *libpcre3* and when I try to install it, I am told that the latest one is already installed! What is going on?